# onClick reload the image in div

Tags: php, html

Here is my code:

```
<div id='captcha'>
<img src='captcha.php'>
<a href=''>Reload Captcha</a>
</div>
```

This is a small bit of code that i have on my page. Line 2 will load a captcha image and i want line 3 to reload only that div and not the whole page, so that the captcha will change.
Is this even possible? please guide me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can force the DOM to reload the image by appending a `#` to it.

Using jQuery:

```
<div id='captcha'>
  <img src='captcha.php' id="captcha_image" />
  <a href='javascript:void(0);' id="reload_captcha">Reload Captcha</a>
</div>

$('#reload_captcha').click(function(event){
  $('#captcha_image').attr('src', $('#captcha_image').attr('src')+'#');
});
```

Answer (score 5):

Just to simply reload you can:

`<img src='captcha.php' onClick="this.src='captcha.php?rand='+Math.random();">`

Random will get rid of browser cache problem and will force to reload it.

Comment: I like that this is a pure JavaScript solution

Answer (score 0):

You could delete the div with javascript `removeElement(...)` and than add the element again to the dom `createElement(...)`. the image should be reloaded then.

Answer (score 0):

With jQuery you can do it like this:

`$("#captcha").load(location.href+" #captcha>*","");`

Where #captcha is ID of the part you want to reload.
To be more specific, this code should do the job:

```
<a href="#" onclick="$('#captcha').load(location.href+' #captcha>*','');return false;">
Reload Captcha
</a>
```